# select a radio button and when i go back to this activity the selection still exists?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-radiobutton

customlist and contain  radiobuttons and I want to  select one radiobutton and it works. But i want to save that raidobutton which i  select. 
I used sharedpreference but i couldnt do it . i know the sharedpreference is the good way to save value in android .
sorry for bad english . 
help me please .

```
public class rowadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
int layoutResourceId;    
private final String[] web;
private final Integer[] imageId;
int selectedPosition = -1;
SharedPreferences sharedPref;

public rowadapter(Activity context,String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
    super(context,R.layout.item_listview, web);
    this.context = context;
    this.web = web;
    this.imageId = imageId;
     sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("position",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public View getView(final int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    backgroundholder holder = null;
    View rowView=row;

        rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview, null, true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);



        holder = new backgroundholder();    
        holder.radiobutton = (RadioButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.radiobutton);
        holder.radiobutton.setChecked(position == selectedPosition);
        holder.radiobutton.setTag(position);
        int checkedpos=sharedPref.getInt("poistion",-1);
        if(checkedpos==position)
        {
           holder.radiobutton.setChecked(true);
        }
        holder.radiobutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view)
              {
                  selectedPosition = (Integer)view.getTag();
                   RadioButton radio = (RadioButton)view;
                   if(radio.isChecked())
                   {
                   Editor editor=sharedPref.edit();
                   editor.putInt("position", selectedPosition);
                   editor.commit();
                   }

                  notifyDataSetInvalidated();
              }
          });        
   return rowView;
static class backgroundholder
{

    RadioButton radiobutton;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a spelling mistake, you've written:

```
int checkedpos=sharedPref.getInt("poistion",-1);
```

but it should be:

```
int checkedpos=sharedPref.getInt("position",-1);
```

For this reason, I usually like to use a constant, so you make an instance variable like:

```
public static final String POSITION = "position";
```

And then access the value like this:

```
int checkedpos = sharedPref.getInt(POSITION, -1);
///...
editor.putInt(POSITION, selectedPosition);
```

Which will make it easier to spot a spelling mistake.

Comment: @user3631823 No probs, would you be so kind as to accept this as an answer? Thanks

Comment: @user3631823 There should be a tick underneath the up/down vote buttons :) Once you click it, it should turn green. Thanks